# Opening Julia plots in VScode not in GKS QTterm

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, plots.jl

When I run a plot command in Julia, plot opens in external GKS QTterm window. How to open plot right there in VScode?

```
using Plots
plot(rand(10))
```

Opened window in QTterm

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the effect you describe comes when `Use Plot Pane` setting is turned off:

```
Settings> Julia > Use Plot Pane
```

Kill Julia process to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. with the suggested settings, plot was still not opening in VScode because I was running Julia file in

> VScode and powershell
> To get the plot in VScode I had to run
> Julia through REPL
> Please refer the attached image.

[image: 1]